# Transforming System of Equation to First order

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I really need some help with the following question:

Question: Given $x'' = 2x'-x+y$  and $y''=3y'+y+4x'+x$,  write the system as a first order system in the form $x'=Ax$, by explcitly mentioning vector $x$ and matrix $A$. Also mention how many initial conditions are needed.

My Approach: The initial conditons I set were: $x=x_1, x'=x_2, x''=(x_2)'$ and $y=y_1, y'=y_2, y''=(y_2)'$
.  So then my system of equation becomes $(x_2)'=2x_2-x_1+y_1$ and $(y_2)'=3y_2+y_1+4x_2+x_1$. Putting it in the form $x'=Ax$, I get
\begin{bmatrix}-1&2&1&0\\1&4&1&3\end{bmatrix} for $A$, but I am confused on what $x$ would be based on my initial conditons. Also I mentioned that $6$ initial conditions were needed . Why is that not right? Is is only $4$ thats needed with  $x''=(x_2)' a$nd $ y''=(y_2)'$  not counted as initial conditions or is there a different answer/reason?